# Flatten a list in RxJava 2

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have been using RxJava 1 for some time but I want to look at RxJava 2. In RxJava 1, I could emit each item of list as follows:

```
List<String> list = ...
Observable.from(list)
    .filter(str -> str.contains("Help")
    .subscribe(...);
```

However, how can I achieve the same with RxJava2? I have tried to use the following but I can't seem to get past the following:

```
Observable.fromArray(list)
// this now passes a list into the stream - there is no Observable::from
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use `fromIterable()` since any `List<T>` extends `Collection<T>` which extends `Iterable<T>`

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
          .filter(str -> str.contains("Help")
          .subscribe(...);
```