# Use RXjava to emit Data from mutiple Arraylists based on Previous Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, rx-java

I have an arraylist like `{"Fruits", "Flowers", "Animals", "Birds"}`

then I have multiple Arraylists like

`Fruits = {"Mango", "Apple", "Banana" }`

`Flowers = {"Rose", "Tulip", "Lily", "Orchid","Daisy" }`

`Animals = {"Lion", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Deer","Horse","Cat" }`

`Birds = {"Owl", "Dove","Sparrow","Goose","Ostrich","Pigeon"}`

how can we create an arraylist using RX java to emit data like

`{"Mango", "Apple", "Banana" ,"Rose", "Tulip", "Lily", "Orchid","Daisy" ,"Lion", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Deer","Horse","Cat","Owl", "Dove","Sparrow","Goose","Ostrich","Pigeon" }`

**The requirement is  call Arraylist data with parameters from the result of the call from the previous arraylist of `{"Fruits", "Flowers", "Animals", "Birds"}`**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537071/flatten-a-list-in-rxjava-2) and your initial `{"Fruits", "Flowers", "Animals", "Birds"}` you can wrap into another array list. And for these two arrays use `concatMap` and then the [operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapIterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) `flatMapIterable`.